# How to simplyfy getting the patch for one changeset in git?

Tags: git, syntax

[git revision](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git-htmldocs.git;a=blob_plain;f=gitrevisions.html;hb=HEAD) syntax is really powerful, but I can't find how to simplify things like:

```
git diff 1a2e^..1a2e
```

without writing tree'sh1 twice?

Is there now "NEXT" syntax, something like:

```
git diff 1a2e^..NEXT
```

OR

```
git changeset 1a2e
```

??

Another "next" syntax which might be useful if 1a2e is a known revision:

```
git cherry-pick 1a2e+NEXT..origin/featureBranch
```

^^ "cherry pick anything from 1a2e to master EXCEPT 1a2e itself"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git show <tree-ish>
```

for instance.

And no, you can not refer to child commit, parent has no knowledge of it. And there may be more than one in no particular order.

Comment: you meant: "You can not refer to parent commit, child has no knowledge of it"?! That's reasonable

Comment: No, _child_ is the correct term, but it depends on how you see the commit tree. The way it's displayed in `git log` and other commands that show more than one commit, it might appear that the commits on top are _parents_ and the ones bellow are _children_, but it's the other way around: the root of the tree is the bottom-most commit, and the one on top is the most recent, youngest commit. Parents are down, not up.

Comment: Listing all children of a commit should be a simple operation (it's a search operation over the whole repository, so maybe not fast, but still simple). I don't see a good way to do it though. Here's my close-enough-to-be-useful attempt: `foo=commitsha1 ; git rev-list --parents $foo.. | awk "/$foo/{print \$1}"`

Comment: @AlanCurry, listing all reachable children is possible, but referring to *one* of them, that is not dependent on a particular repository is not.

Answer (score 0):

you can do `git log -1 -p sha1`.

Comment: yes but that command is used so infrequently, so a modifier to log is something that sticks in your mind more easily.

Answer (score 0):

I've build a q'n'd workaround [git-getnext](http://code.childno.de/marcel/src/master/bin/git-getnext)
which will get the child id in current branch from git log

Comment: you can get next commit using `git log --topo-order --reverse --format=%H $commit..HEAD | head -n 2 | tail -n 1`, BTW.

Comment: ;-) I was tired, of course you can replace `head -n 2 | tail -n 1` with `sed -n -e 2p`.

Comment: or just tail -n1 because {{sed -n -e 2p}} will give the second but last but not the last ;)

Comment: sed gives me the second line, which is exactly what I need, because I have a reverse order, so it would be a last but one going from head to your commit.